# Why contructing a MATLAB struct object with an empty cell it creates an empty struct instead?

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

I want to construct an struct object with three properties:

```
arg1 = 42;
arg2 = 'test';
arg3 = cell(0);
```

But if I try to initialize that object:

```
struct('arg1', arg1, 'arg2', arg2, 'arg3', arg3);
```

It returns an empty struct:

```
ans = 

  0×0 empty struct array with fields:

    arg1
    arg2
    arg3
```

I figured out the empty cell is the culprit, so if i initialize it without the empty cell it returns a correct value:

```
ans = 

  struct with fields:

    arg1: 42
    arg2: 'test'
    arg3: []
```

But I need my code to work with empty cells, and I don't know **if** or **where** they will be in one of the fields.

Is there a way to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) behaviour:

> `s = struct(field,value)` creates a structure array with the specified `field` and `values`. The `value` input argument can be any data type, such as a numeric, logical, character, or cell array.
>
> - If any of the `value` inputs is a nonscalar cell array, then `s` has the same dimensions as the nonscalar cell array. [...]
> - **If `value` is an empty cell array `{}`, then `s` is an empty (0-by-0) structure. To specify an empty field and keep the values of the other fields, use `[]` as a value input instead**

The take-away for you is the last line.

To get around this, you will have to do checks like

```
if iscell( argX ) && isempty( argX )
    argX = [];
end
```

If you always just have 3 items in your struct then this is fairly simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

[@Wolfie's explanation for the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53780025/7328782) is correct.

The workaround is to put the data in cell arrays like so:

```
>> struct('arg1', {arg1}, 'arg2', {arg2}, 'arg3', {arg3})

ans = 

  struct with fields:

    arg1: 42
    arg2: 'test'
    arg3: {}
```

This works because of this line in the documentation:

> - If any of the value inputs is a nonscalar cell array, then s has the same dimensions as the nonscalar cell array.

So we make all the value inputs cell arrays. `{arg3}` is the same as `{{}}`, a cell array with one element: an empty cell array.

Note that it is possible to create a struct array with this syntax:

```
>> struct('arg1', {1,2,3}, 'arg2', {arg2}, 'arg3', {arg3})

ans = 

  1×3 struct array with fields:

    arg1
    arg2
    arg3
```

Because the `'arg1'` argument is a cell array with 3 elements, the created struct array also has 3 elements. The cell arrays with a single element are replicated across all cell arrays.